# Reserving memory for DMA usage

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, driver, dma

I am trying to make use of a contiguous memory i reserved while passing the "mem" parameter to Linux when booting.

Now, i have the physical address of this space i reserved earlier, and the length of it, and i wish to make use of this reserved space for DMA purposes in my driver.

Normally i would use `dma_alloc_coherent()` , and if i were using CMA i would use that too, but in this case, its different.

Now, i have read that an acceptable way of mapping a physical space to kernel virtual space is to use `ioremap`

And, an acceptable way of "taking over" a contiguous space for DMA purposes is to use `dma_map_single` (mapping it for bus address)

I'm having trouble combining the two. `ioremap` works and returns a virtual address. Now, i have read that this is no ordinary virtual address and i should only be using access methods to read/write from this memory.

Thing is, when i try to pass this virtual address to `dma_map_single` , it doesn't report an error, but i suspect that this is wrong.

Am i doing it right? What can i do to make it work like it should?

10x

Comment: I'm too lazy to search, but on this site this question happens once per year.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I'm not skilled at searching, but I did search and found different variants but nothing like my case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing right
You don't need to allocate the memory because you already set it on boot time but you need to use dam_map_single to prevent cache problems for example if you want to do a DMA from memory to the device but the RAM is not synchronised with the L2 cache (the cache has a newer version) you will get the wrong data so you need to map and unmap before and after the DMA operation

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't sure passing dma_map_single the ioremapped address is right.

Comment: @Liran Sorry to hack the thread, But Memory mapping created using ioremap is not cached .So can it be directly passed to a device for the dma?

Comment: If you copy from one io memory to other, it's ok but most of time you copy from DDR to device (or opposite) and the DDR can be cached

Comment: If we reserve DDR at boot time, and DDR memory is ioremapped to kernel virtual address space. As per my understanding, this memory is non-cached. And if underlying platform does not support IOMMU, I think we can just pass the physical address to the device and ask to do the DMA. Is my understanding wrong?

Comment: You are right but you still need to "tell" the CPU that you are doing a DMA request so it won't touch the bus until it ends see here an example http://www.discoversdk.com/knowledge-base/dma-example